# TexWorks: how do I add custom compiling sequences into the selection of available compiling sequences?

Tags: texworks

I am using MikTex 2.9 with TexWorks 0.6.3 as editor. As I frequently have to execute a compile sequence

XeLaTeX -> PdfLatex -> Bibtex -> PdfLatex

which I currently have to do manually, I would like to put this sequence into some kind of wrapper (batch file?) and call this wrapper from the dropdown menu within TexWorks:

[image]

Is this possible?

Comment: XeLaTeX and PdfLaTeX at-the-same-time? Are you sure?

Comment: Well - I have to call them in a sequence as I call a Python *.py file via pythontex which seems to work only (in my case..) if I process my TEX file with XeLaTeX first and then PdfLaTeX for the final output

Comment: If you need XeLaTeX, my advice is: don't use PdfLaTeX at all... XeLaTeX still produces PDF files.

Comment: I have/want to PdfLatex as I am calculating a hash code (as unique document identifier) from the text-file content via \pdfmdfivesum file {\jobname}}. Is something like that possible via XeLaTeX?

Comment: it is really quite hard to have a file that works unchanged with xetex and pdftex, and almost impossible to get the same fonts being used. Are you really sure your pipeline is correct?

Comment: xetex has `\mdfivesum` which is the same as the pdftex command apart from the more sensible name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TeXworks keeps its Typesetting Preferences in a plain text file called tools.ini within its configuration folder.  NOTE the contents will vary considerably depending on the TeX engine, **here is one with MiKTeX entries.**

[image]

You thus have two options

a) Edit it directly (ensure you have made a backup, **DO NOT edit** with TeXworks  nor **whilst TeXworks is running** ) HOWEVER for your case this may not help much as it is what some may call a "flat" format see how the chain of commands `XeLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTeX` has only one program called texify.exe.

For your use we need to specify a single program to carry out your desired options   `XeLaTeX -> PdfLatex -> Bibtex -> PdfLatex`.

b) Add entries to a new Processing tool definition inside TeXworks Preferences, HOWEVER we have just seen that also is subject to the same limitation of ONE process handler at a time.

**So what is the best approach?, well there is latexmk and araura amongst other batch handlers** these remove much trial and error.

Since we can see the contents of the ini we could home brew fairly easily and add an extra tool

NOTE I have 18 so the next one to be  added is 019 It **will** differ for you. the -shell-escape should be optional try with **and without**

```
[019]
name="XeLaTeX,pdfLaTeX++BibTeX,pdfLaTeX"
program=MyTool.cmd
arguments=$fullname, -shell-escape
showPdf=true
```

MyTool.cmd must be somewhere on "path" , ideally alongside the MiKTeX binaries, but that is not essential if they are also on path.

```
Rem highly simplified to only take %1 = $fullname as passed by MiKTeX NOTE filenames with spaces are most likely to fail. (that has not been but could be allowed for)
Rem optionally %2 passes --shell-escape
::
miktex-xetex.exe  %2 --synctex=1 -undump=xelatex %1
texify.exe --pdf --engine=xetex --synctex=1 --clean %1
miktex-pdftex.exe %2 --synctex=1 -undump=pdflatex %1
::
pause whilst testing
:: remove this pause once testing is done
```

The pause is only needed on first run to check in console it is found and working, normally there would be more messaging but this is a quick and dirty proof of concept.