# How to use char č in \choicemenu

Tags: characters

I'm starting with LaTex and I'm doing on fillable form. One of options in form is dropdown list (\choicemenu). One of choices is "Oče", but when I compile file into PDF the letter č becomes c (Oče becomes Oce).

Here is the part of the code:

```
\ChoiceMenu[width=5em, print,combo,default=Izberite...,name=odd, ]{Vlagatelj je:}    {Mati, Oče, Druga oseba} \\
```

I want to use this type of choice, because it works on all devices (including Android).
I use utf8 encoding.

Thanks for help.

This is larger part of code:

```
\usepackage[english, slovene]{babel} % 'french', 'german', 'spanish', 'danish', etc.
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{mathdots}
\usepackage[classicReIm]{kpfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper,includeheadfoot,margin=1 cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lmodern}

% You can include more LaTeX packages here 
\newcommand\tab[1][0.2cm]{\hspace*{#1}}
\newcommand\ltab[1][0.5cm]{\hspace*{#1}}

\geometry{
 headheight=0pt,headsep=0pt, foot=0pt,
 }

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{slovene}
%\selectlanguage{english} % remove comment delimiter ('%') and select language if required

\begin{Form}
\begin{tabular}{|m{5cm}|m{13cm}|}
  \hline    
  & \normalsize Sime text \\  
  & \\
  \large \textbf{Some text} & \large Some text \\
  \large {\textbf{Some text}} & \large Some text\\
  & \large Some text\\
  & \large Some text\\
\hline

 \large {\begin{flushright}Some text\end{flushright}} & \ChoiceMenu[width=5em, combo,default=Izberite...,name=odd, ]{Vlagatelj je:}    {Mati, O\v{c}e, Druga oseba} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Which engine did you use to compile? And which PDF viewer did you use? If I compile your code (after making a minimal example out of it) with `xelatex` and then view it with Okular then I get the correct output (with the accented č).

Comment: And also Evince and Acrobat Reader work fine.

Comment: I use TeXworks (desktop app), and Adobe Acrobat DC as a viewer.

Comment: Show a complete example not only a snippet. That makes it much easier to test your issue.

Comment: Texworks is your editor, I was asking about the engine/compiler. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/490172/, that screenshot is in German but it should be the same for you, it that list you can choose the compiler. When you choose XeLaTeX it should work properly.

Comment: sorry this is still a part (and now it is too large). Try to make a *complete* but concise example.

Comment: Thanks. Now I have letter č in dropdown menu, but letters š, č and ž are mising in all text.

Comment: I solved problems with Š, Č and Ž. Thanks again.